# Wait for mysqli::multi_query to finish before executing next statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, mysqli

I have some code that uses `Mysqli::multi_query` to drop and rebuild a development database from a flat `.sql` file. After rebuilding the mysqli connection is closed and the code then reconnects to that DB with `PDO` to run queries against it.

```php
/* Drop and Rebuild DB using mysqli::multi_query */
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die('Failed to connect to MySQL: (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$query = file_get_contents("DROPandREBUILD.sql");

if (!$mysqli->multi_query($query))
    die("Failed to refresh db: $this->target_db");

$mysqli->close();

/* Execute queries against rebuilt database using PDO */
try {
    $sth = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $ass);
    $test1 = $sth->query("SELECT * FROM tbl");
    var_dump($sth->errorInfo());
    $test2 = $sth->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM tbl");
    var_dump($sth->errorInfo());
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Output from 1st `var_dump` (`$test1`):

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>string(5) "00000"
  [1]=>NULL
  [2]=>NULL
}
object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>string(31) "SELECT * FROM tbl"
}
```

Output from 2nd var_dump (`$test2`):

```
array(3) {
   [0]=>string(5) "42S02"
   [1]=>int(1146)
   [2]=>string(45) "Table 'db.tbl' doesn't exist"
}
bool(false)
```

Why does the query from `$test2` fail? If I remove the `mysqli` code bock then everything works perfectly. Both queries are running against the same `tbl` in the same `db`. Is there something going on that is asynchronous and if so how do I force my script to wait for the `mysqli::multi_query` to finish executing before instantiating `PDO`?

Comment: @KevinLabécot - If I change it then I get the same result for `$test1->errorInfo()` . `$test2->errorInfo()` produces `Call to a member function errorInfo() on a non-object`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know this for a fact but I am assuming that the connection is not actually being closed when you run `$mysqli->close();` because there are `X` resultset still unprocessed or free'd.

You could try this to see if it clears the issue :-

```
$query = file_get_contents("DROPandREBUILD.sql");

if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            $result->free();
        }

    } while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
}
$mysqli->close();
```

You could also add some code that actually checks the results of each of the multiple queries if you were so inclined.

Comment: You're an absolute lifesaver! Thanks! There's one issue with your script that causes a strict standards notice. Can you edit your answer to  change the `while` statement to `while($mysqli->more_results());` and move the `mysqli->next_result()` to the top of the `do` block - as soon as you do this I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Adam, not sure your suggestion made sence to me, as I believe the first result is already available for processing and you only need the `next_result()` to collect result 2,3,etc. I have changed code to use the more_results() as part of the `while` statement. Out of interest what was the STRICT message.

Comment: The STRICT msg was: `Strict Standards: mysqli::next_result() [mysqli.next-result]: There is no next result set. Please, call mysqli_more_results()/mysqli::more_results() to check whether to call this function/method`